# Show that $\log(x+1)-\log(x)<\frac{1}{x}$ for $x >0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

Show that $\log(x+1)-\log(x)<\frac{1}{x}$ for $x >0$.

I was told this was very easy, but I don't see how to solve it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $\log(1+t)$ is  strictly concave and therefore its graph stays under its tangent line at $0$: for any $t\not=0$ and $t>-1$,
$$\log(1+t)< t.$$
Your inequality is equivalent to
$$\log(x+1)-\log(x)=\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)< \frac1x.$$

Comment: @Nicolas FRANCOIS See my edited answer. Anyway I like yours (+1)!

Comment: thank you, I must be sleepy :-) And I teach my students to recognize those identities :-P

Answer (score 5):

Apply the mean value theorem: if $f$ is differentiable on $]a,b[$ and continuous on $[a,b]$, then 
$$(\exists c\in]a,b[)\,f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$$
So here :
$$\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)=(x+1-x)\ln'(c)=\frac1c< \frac1x$$
because $x+1>c>x$.

Rmk : you can also study the function $f:x\mapsto \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)-\frac1x$...

Answer (score 4):

Let $x>0$.

$f: t\mapsto \ln(t)$ is continuous at $[x,x+1]$ and differentiable at $(x,x+1)$, thus by MVT,

$\exists c\in(x,x+1)\;:\; $

$f(x+1)-f(x)=(x+1-x)f'(c)$

$\implies \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)=\frac{1}{c}$

and

$$x<c<x+1 \iff   \frac{1}{x+1}<\frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{x}.$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{x+1}<\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)<\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ . Set $u=1/x$ and then after making a good figure you will see that $\log(1+u)\le u$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this with $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}-\ln(x+1)+\ln x=\int\limits_x^{x+1}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{t})dt>0\enspace$ because of $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{t}>0\enspace$ for $\enspace t>x$ .

Answer (score 0):

If $t\geq 0$,We have:$$ e^t\geq t+1$$ So:$$t\geq \ln{(t+1)}$$  Let:$t=\frac{1}{x}$  then:$$\ln{(1+\frac{1}{x})}\leq \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: this is essentially same answer as @Robert Z 's answer, no point in copying answers.

Comment: I'm sorry the answer is repeated, but I did not replicate the answer

Comment: No problem but in future take care as this can attract downvotes and harsh comments.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reminders, and I think we got this proof in both positive and negative directions