# Proof on property on increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, monotone-functions

I struggle on the proof of the following property  : 
let $f$ be an increasing function, and suppose $L=\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty} f(x)$ exists

Then 
$$L\geq f(x)$$
Samely for a decreasing function : 
$$L\leq f(x)$$

This can be used to prove inequalities when we know the variations (see my question about inequality without using an Integral for example : [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3147302/516412)) 
Could you help me? 
Thanks,

T.D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition of limit. Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Then we have a positive real number $N$ such that $$L-\epsilon<f(x) <L+\epsilon$$ whenever $x>N$. Since $f$ is increasing it follows that $$f(x) <L+\epsilon$$ for all $x$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary it follows that $f(x) \leq L$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that an increasing function $f$ can be equal to $L+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \gt 0$. Then in order for $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ to equal $L$ the function must *decrease* by $\epsilon$ which means that the function is not increasing. A similar argument can be made for the decreasing function.

Comment: the function must *decrease* by **arbitrarily close** to $\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Say, for some $x_0$, $f(x_0)>L.$ 
Let $\epsilon=f(x_0)-L$, so $\epsilon>0.$

Then, because  $L=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x),$ there is $X$ such that for all $x>X$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$

But then, taking some $x_1$ greater than $X$ and $x_0$, $f(x_1) \lt L+  \epsilon$,  so $f(x_1)<f(x_0),$

so $f(x)$ is not increasing.

Comment: Can you a explain in your answer why $f(x_1)<L+\varepsilon$ moreover would $x_1=|X|+|x_0|$ work?

Comment: Since $x_1>X$, $|f(x_1)-L|<\epsilon$, so $L-\epsilon<f(x_1)<L+\epsilon$

Comment: How about $x_1=|X|+|x_0|+1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be interesting to prove that if $f$ is increasing in a left neighborhood $U$ of $c$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\sup\{f(x):x\in U\}
$$
Here $c$ can also be $\infty$, with a (left) neighborhood meaning any set containing an interval of the form $(K,\infty)$. Also the supremum can by $\infty$.

Let me do the proof with $c=\infty$ and you can work it out for the finite case.

Suppose first $f$ is bounded on $U$. Then $L=\sup\{f(x):x\in U\}$ is finite. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $x_0\in U$ such that $f(x_0)>L-\varepsilon$. Since $f$ is increasing over $U$, for every $x>x_0$ we have $f(x)>L-\varepsilon$, which implies
$$
L-\varepsilon<f(x)\le L<L+\varepsilon
$$
and so $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we conclude $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$.

The proof for the case when $f$ is unbounded on $U$ is similar; in this case $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.